# Printing PDF bytes directly to printer

Tags: command-line, printing, pdf

I am working on .NET core framework. I want to do printing on Ubuntu.
The current approach I am using is creating a PDF, saving it on my machine, and then printing this PDF using the `lpr` command.

Now what I want is to send PDF bytes directly to printer, instead of sending the PDF file path.

I want to do this as this will avoid saving of PDF file on machine for every print command, and then deleting it after printing completes.

So is bytes-printing possible in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried `cat your.pdf | lpr -P "yourprinter"` ?

Comment: I want to avoid creation of PDF, I want to read PDF from memory stream. Is this possible in Linux?

Comment: Not sure but you may call `lpr` and give it stream you want through standard input channel, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx